# How to pass data (using enum class) to other screen in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I tried passing data to my `PreviewScreen()` using nav arguments in my jetpack compose project. But its not working propely. Here are the problems ->

- Its always showing the else statement even the data that is passed is equal to `PreviewType.Image`
- Its showing the Toast multiple times

Here is my code that i have tried so far.

NavigationGraph code :-

```
NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = HomeDestination.route,
        modifier = modifier
    ){
        composable(HomeDestination.route){
            HomeScreen(
                onMediaItemClick = {
                    navController.navigate(PreviewScreenDestination.route + "/$it")
                }
            )
        }
        composable(
            PreviewScreenDestination.route + "/{preview_type}",
            arguments = listOf(
               navArgument("preview_type"){
                   type = NavType.EnumType(PreviewType::class.java)
               }
            )
        ){
            PreviewScreen(mediaList = emptyList())
        }
    }
```

The `PreviewScreen()` code :-

```
@Composable
fun PreviewScreen(
    mediaList: List<LocalMediaModel>
){
    val navController= rememberNavController()
    val previewType = navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<PreviewType>("preview_type")
    val context = LocalContext.current

    when(previewType){
        PreviewType.Image -> { Toast.makeText(context, "i'm image show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
        PreviewType.Video -> { Toast.makeText(context, "i'm video show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
        else -> { Toast.makeText(context, "i'm combined show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
    }
}
```

Enum class code :-

```
enum class PreviewType {
    Image,
    Video,
    Combined
}
```